# Create Nested Dict from paths and values

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

i need help with similar request raised in [Python: recursively create dictionary from paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017045/python-recursively-create-dictionary-from-paths) but my path is having list also.
I have paths sometime with index also like below

```
PATH       VALUE
/a/b/c      'Hi'
/a/b/d       1
/a/c/d       1
/b/c/d       1
/a/e[0]/f    1
/a/e[1]/g    2
/b/x/y[1]    'thank'
/b/x/y[2]    'you'
/b/j/b/c     2
/b/j/b/d     1
/a/e[2]/k[0]/s     '2D_1'
/a/e[2]/k[1]/s     '2D_2'
```

Expected output Dictionary i am looking for is below :

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": "Hi",
            "d": 1
        },
        "c": {
            "d": 1
        },
        "e": [
            {
                "f": 1
            },
            {
                "g": 2
            },
            {
                "k": [
                    {
                        "s": "2D_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "s": "2D_2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": 1
        },
        "x": {
            "y": [
                null,
                "thank",
                "you"
            ]
        },
        "j": {
            "b": {
                "c": 2,
                "d": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Path can be more than 4 parts (any number) .
Recursive way to handle this and create the dict from paths and values ?

i tried with below sample code , but stuck with list processing.

```
import re

def create_dict(data,path,value):
    nodes = path.split('/')
    thisdict = data
    index = -1
    for node in nodes[:-1]:
        keyislist = False
        if '[' in node :
            index = int(re.findall(r"\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]", node)[0])
            node = node.split('[')[0]
            keyislist = True
        if (node not in thisdict):
            if keyislist:
                thisdict[node] = []
            elif isinstance(thisdict,dict):
                thisdict[node] = {}
        if isinstance(thisdict[node],dict):
            thisdict = thisdict[node]
        elif isinstance(thisdict[node],list):
            thisdict[node].insert(index,thisdict[node])
    thisdict[nodes[-1]] = value
    return data

data = {}
keys = '/a/b/c[0]/d/e/f'
value = 123456
path = keys[1:]
print(create_dict(data,path,value))

print('---------------')

keys = '/a/b/c[1]/d/e/g'
value = 'ABCDEFG'
path = keys[1:]
print(create_dict(data,path,value))
```

Also added 2 more path . order of path k[1] can be first then later K[0] path.

```
/a/e[2]/k[1]/s     '2D_2'
/a/e[2]/k[0]/s     '2D_1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the linked code, the expected result is invalid, so I made a guess or two as to your intent.

Firstly,

```
{'b':
    {'c': 'Hi' },
    {'d': 1 }
},
```

is a syntax error. You can't have two values for a key like this. `'b'` has to be either a list or a dict. Since you've taken pains to add lists to the specification, I asssume this should be a dict.

Secondly, `{'y' : ['thank' , 'you']}` seems like a surprising result to expect from

```
/b/x/y[1]    'thank'
/b/x/y[2]    'you'
```

which uses indexes 1 and 2. If you want the original result, use `.append` (confusing!), or fix the indexes in the input (not confusing).

Beyond that, parsing the new list requirement involves picking out the index and element with a regex and using the index as well as the key to dive into the next level of nesting.

```py
import json
import re

def add_path(d, path, val):
    path = path.split("/")[1:]

    for i, e in enumerate(path):
        if re.search(r".?\[\d+\]$", e):
            e, idx = re.fullmatch(r"(.+)\[(\d+)\]", e).groups()
            idx = int(idx)

            if e not in d:
                d[e] = [None] * (idx + 1)
            elif len(d[e]) <= idx:
                d[e] += [None] * (idx - len(d[e]) + 1)

            if i == len(path) - 1:
                d[e][idx] = val 
            elif not d[e][idx]:    
                d[e][idx] = {}

            d = d[e][idx]
        else:
            if i == len(path) - 1:
                d[e] = val
            else:
                if e not in d:
                    d[e] = {}

                d = d[e]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = """
    /a/b/c      'Hi'
    /a/b/d       1
    /a/c/d       1
    /b/c/d       1
    /a/e[0]/f    1
    /a/e[1]/g    2
    /b/x/y[1]    'thank'
    /b/x/y[2]    'you'
    /b/j/b/c     2
    /b/j/b/d     1
    """
    d = {}

    def clean(x):   
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            return x.strip(" '")

    for path, val in [[clean(x) for x in re.split(r"\s{4,}", x)][1:] 
                      for x in data.split("\n") if x.strip()]:
        add_path(d, path, val)
    
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": "Hi",
            "d": 1
        },
        "c": {
            "d": 1
        },
        "e": [
            {
                "f": 1
            },
            {
                "g": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": 1
        },
        "x": {
            "y": [
                null,
                "thank",
                "you"
            ]
        },
        "j": {
            "b": {
                "c": 2,
                "d": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cleaning this code up a bit is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you ggorlen for awesome work , i checked it is working for the sample i shared before, but when tested with multiple nested array (array inside array, any limit) , it is not working. It is adding null value in first index. I updated two path , please try once.

Comment: The new input you're asking about isn't valid if you mean it to be part of the previous structure. I strongly recommend showing only a valid dict as output. I already explained the nulls -- if you have one element `foo[2]` with no `[0]` or `[1]`, why would you make `[2]` as `[0]`? That's really surprising. It makes more sense for there to be nulls in the missing array positions. Following your logic of moving 2 -> 0, imagine if you had `a[1]/something`, then `a[0]/something` later. Does `a[0]` overwrite `a[1]`? This makes no sense to mess with the indices -- it'd reverse the elements.

Comment: That said, I did have a bug where I was overwriting the list element that already existed which I fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You are awesome and cool . Thank you ggorlen.

Comment: Adding to you question , let say first path came as foo[2] , so we will enter null in [0] and [1] , you are right , later down the line , i will get foo[1] and foo[2] path and it should update to those null. I was expecting this only . Sorry if i confused u, but you gave the answer already now. Its working.

Comment: OK, glad it all worked out. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Haha. Pretty similar to @ggorlen's.

```
import re
import pprint

class Parser(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.index_pattern = re.compile(r'([^[]*)\[(\d+)\]')

  def Add(self, tree, path, value):
    for seg in path[:-1]:
      match = self.index_pattern.fullmatch(seg)
      if match:
        lst, ix = self.AddList(match, tree, dict)
        tree = lst[ix]
      else:
        node = tree[seg] if seg in tree else {}
        tree[seg] = node
        tree = node

    match = self.index_pattern.fullmatch(path[-1])
    if match:
      lst, ix = self.AddList(match, tree, lambda: None)
      lst[ix] = value
    else:
      tree[path[-1]] = value

  @staticmethod
  def AddList(match, tree, ctor):
    name = match.group(1)
    ix = int(match.group(2))
    lst = tree[name] if name in tree else []
    lst.extend(ctor() for i in range(ix - len(lst) + 1))
    tree[name] = lst
    return lst, ix

  def Process(self, data):
    tree = {}
    for path, value in data.items():
      self.Add(tree, path.split('/')[1:], value)
    return tree

def Run():
  data = {
    '/a/b/c': 'Hi',
    '/a/b/d': 1,
    '/a/c/d': 1,
    '/b/c/d': 1,
    '/a/e[0]/f': 1,
    '/a/e[1]/g': 2,
    '/b/x/y[1]': 'thank',
    '/b/x/y[2]': 'you',
    '/b/j/b/c': 2,
    '/b/j/b/d': 1,
  }
  pprint.pprint(Parser().Process(data))

Run()
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'Hi', 'd': 1}, 'c': {'d': 1}, 'e': [{'f': 1}, {'g': 2}]},
 'b': {'c': {'d': 1},
       'j': {'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 1}},
       'x': {'y': [None, 'thank', 'you']}}}
```

Comment: Awesome Gene you too. Great Answer. I ran it few time , its working properly anyway. I will debug and try to learn ur and ggorlen way both.