Parsing dict like structure to dict
I want to parse this input to output.
input = {
    "a.b.c[0][0].d": "i",
    "a.b.c[0][1].e-f": "j",
    "a.b.c[0][2].g-h[0]": "x",
    "a.b.c[0][3].g-h[1]": "y",
    "a.b.c[0][4].g-h[2]": "z",
    "x": [
        {
            "b": {
                "x.y.z": "a"
            },
        },
        {
            "b": {
                "d.f.a": "b"
            },
        },
        {
            "b": {
                "g.h.q": "c"
            },
        },
    ],
}

output = {
    "a": {
        "b" : {
            "c": [
                    [
                        {
                            {"d": "i"},
                            {"e": "j"},
                            {"g": ["x", "y", "z"]},
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
    "x": [
        {
            "b": {
                "x": { "y": { "z": "a" } }
            }
        },
        {
            "b": {
                "d": { "f": { "a": "b" } }
            }
        },
        {
            "b": {
                "g": { "h": { "q": "c" } }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have done for simple keys however I am stuck at the list indices keys e.g. a[0][0] , which should create a list of values.
I am missing the parse for this type of keys. It should take the key and return a list depending how many level deep it needs to go based on the indices.
def convert(self, data: Dict):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        new_dict = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            if not key or key is None or key == '':
                continue
            parts = key.split(".") if "." in key else key.split("_")
            current_dict = new_dict
            for part in parts[:-1]:
                #print("Current Dict", current_dict)
                current_dict.setdefault(part, {})
                current_dict = current_dict[part]
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                current_dict[parts[-1]] = self.convert(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                # Handle lists containing nested dictionaries
                new_list = []
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, dict):
                        new_list.append(self.convert(item))
                    elif isinstance(item, str) and "," in item:
                        # Split comma-separated string and convert to list of strings
                        new_list.extend(item.split(","))
                    else:
                        new_list.append(item)
                current_dict[parts[-1]] = new_list
            else:
                current_dict[parts[-1]] = value
        return new_dict
    else:
        return data
      
print(convert(input))

This results in:
{'a': {'b': {'c[0][0]': {'d': 'i'}, 'c[0][1]': {'e-f': 'j'}, 'c[0][2]': {'g-h[0]': 'x'}, 'c[0][3]': {'g-h[1]': 'y'}, 'c[0][4]': {'g-h[2]': 'z'}}}, 'x': [{'b': {'x': {'y': {'z': 'a'}}}}, {'b': {'d': {'f': {'a': 'b'}}}}, {'b': {'g': {'h': {'q': 'c'}}}}]}


Does this answer your question? Create nested dictionary from keys seperated by dot(.) in python

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That doesn't address the case of [number], which is the problem this question has.

I didnt know about this question. However it is only talking about the keys with dot separator. My question is regarding the list indices in the keys itself.

Check if part is in the format [index] and use different code that creates a nested list instead of a nested dictionary.

@Barmar Can you please post that as an answer with a snippet ?
I have been staring at it for a while, not getting any ideas.

At every step where you have "a key", check if that key contains [. If so, switch from setting the current container to a new dict, to setting the current container to a new list while also setting a current_index that is normally None for dictionary keys to "the list index you need" when dealing with lists (so: change the name current_dict to something more generic, because it might not be a dict at all)

I think this would be 15-20 minutes of coding for me, but I'm off to lunch now.

Also, there is some more searching you can do here, e.g. I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68786743/create-nested-dict-from-paths-and-values which might be closer to what you're asking about.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It seeems similar. I will try the answers provided in that question. And update here.

I have come up with this: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/YQZA , however not able to update the latest dict. Any pointers?
